# undefined method `exists?' for ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise, ruby-1.9.3

I have Builder and User model with email field, I want to make email as unique in both model. Below validation method is working fine when i put in Builder model but not in User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,:confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at, :unconfirmed_email, :provider,:uid, :name, :oauth_token, :oauth_expires_at
validate :check_email_exists

def check_email_exists
if Builder.exists?(:email => self.email)
  errors.add(:email,"User already exists with this email, try another email")
end
end
```

Error is:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create 

app/models/user.rb:30:in `check_email_exists'

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"EiFhJta51puZ7HZA3YzhopsKL2aJWllkl8geo3cL3gc=",
"user"=>{"email"=>"builder@gmail.com",
"password"=>"[FILTERED]",
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
"commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

What is the reason of error? I am trying to resolve it from lot of days but unsuccess.

This is my builder model

```
class Builder < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,

validate :email_exists

def email_exists
if User.exists?(:email => self.email)
  errors.add(:email,"User already exists with this email, try another email")
end
end
```

let abc@gmail.com is already there in User, Builder sign up form will tell user already exists try another email if I sign up with abc@gmail.com in Builder sign up form, that means email_exists is working fine in builder model but why throws error if i check in User model, although code is right.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Builder
```

Error occurs:
    Exiting
    /home/rails/Desktop/realestate/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized    constant ActiveRecord::Builder (NameError)
    from /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in`block in constantize'

Comment: is `Builder` a model in your database?

Comment: yes I have two models User and Builder created from Devise. If email exists in Builder it should not saved in User and vice versa.

Comment: Can you clarify this: "Below validation method is working fine when i put in Builder model but not in User model." I don't quite get the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from the error that `Builder` is referring to the `ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder` module which is defined in the ActiveRecord scope.

Try accessing your model with `::Builder`, so:

```
  if ::Builder.exists?(email: email)
```

Comment: Thank you so much AJcodez, really this save my time. it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use default validation for uniqueness

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true, :message => "User already exists with this email, try another email"
  ...
end
```

Also in above menioned code, you should use User model instead of Builder

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def check_email_exists
    if User.exists?(:email => self.email)
      errors.add(:email,"User already exists with this email, try another email")
    end
  end 
  ...
end
```

Comment: Aman, you don't even need this validation when using Devise which has already included similar. OP's question is about crossing models.

Comment: @Aman Garg: email is by default unique in devise model. Billy Chan is saying true.